# RabbitMQ Play Java Akka

Tags: java, playframework, rabbitmq, akka

I am using Play Framework 2.2.2 and I am implementing a RabbitMQ consumer application using JavaAkka (Akka Actor System). So I have a MainActor that is initialized when the Play application comes up using Global.OnStart functions. The MainActor creates a RabbitMQ channel and then starts a consuming from a queue. Each message in that queue is a name of another queue that has to assigned to another child actor or sub actor that has to start consuming from the queue mentioned in the message. So essentially, I have one MainActor that is subscribed to ONE RabbitMQ queue and several child actors that are created by the Main actor, each of the child actor are subscribed to their own RabbitMQ queues. The problem is that I can't bring up more than 7 child actors for some reason. I suspect it is the while(true) construct in the child actor that waits for messages from RabbitMQ. Here is my implementation:

**Main Actor:**

```
import play.Logger;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;

import java.io.IOException;

import akka.actor.Props;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;

import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.QueueingConsumer;
import play.libs.Akka;
import util.RabbitMQConnection;

public class MainActor extends UntypedActor {

@Override
public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {

        try{
            Connection connection = RabbitMQConnection.getConnection();
            Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

            String main_queue_name = ConfigFactory.load().getString("rabbitmq.default_queue");

            channel.queueDeclare(main_queue_name, false, false, false, null);

            QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
            channel.basicConsume(main_queue_name, true, consumer);

            while (true) {

                QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
                String message = new String(delivery.getBody());

                System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");

                ActorRef childActor = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(childActor.class));
                childActor.tell(message, getSelf());
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Child Actor:**

```
import play.Logger;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import play.libs.Akka;
import play.libs.Json;

import akka.actor.UntypedActor;

import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.QueueingConsumer;
import util.RabbitMQConnection;


public class childActor extends UntypedActor {

@Override
public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {

    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    String queue_name = ow.writeValueAsString(msg);

    try{
        Connection connection = RabbitMQConnection.getConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.queueDeclare(queue_name, false, false, false, null);

        QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
        channel.basicConsume(queue_name, true, consumer);

        while (true) {
            QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
            String message = new String(delivery.getBody());


            JsonNode jsonMsg = Json.parse(message);

            // Call some function to process the message

        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not using the Actor correctly in this case. In my opinion you should not have a while(true) inside of a `receive` method for a given actor. Also, `QueueingConsumer` was deprecated and the rabbitmq guys recommend to implement you consumer using the interface `Consumer` or the default no-op implementation `DefaultConsumer`.

The way I would do it is:

- Implement a customized consumer for rabbitmq that will send a message to the actor every time it gets something.
- Use that implementation for the main actor. Send the queue name as a message and start a new child actor with the queue name as a constructor field.
- Use that implementation for the child actors. Send the message received to the actor and do the JSON parsing in the actor itself.

Some code here: (**WARNING:** NOT COMPILED OR TEST)

Custom rabbitmq consumer:

```
public class MyCustomRabbitMQConsumer extends DefaultConsumer {

    private ActorRef destinationActor;

    public MyCustomRabbitMQConsumer(ActorRef destinationActor) {
        this.destinationActor = destinationActor;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) {
        destinationActor.tell(new String(body));
    }

}
```

Main actor:

```
import play.Logger;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;

import java.io.IOException;

import akka.actor.Props;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;

import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.QueueingConsumer;
import play.libs.Akka;
import util.RabbitMQConnection;

public class MainActor extends UntypedActor {

    private MyCustomRabbitMQConsumer rabbitConsumer;

    @Override
    public void preStart() {
        Connection connection = RabbitMQConnection.getConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        String main_queue_name = ConfigFactory.load().getString("rabbitmq.default_queue");
        channel.queueDeclare(main_queue_name, false, false, false, null);

        rabbitConsumer = new MyCustomRabbitMQConsumer(getSelf());
        channel.basicConsume(main_queue_name, true, rabbitConsumer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {
        if(msg instanceOf String) {
            String queueName = (String) msg;
            System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + queueName + "'");
            getContext().actorOf(Props.create(childActor.class, queueName));
        }
    }
}
```

ChildActor:

```
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;

import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.QueueingConsumer;
import util.RabbitMQConnection;


public class ChildActor extends UntypedActor {

    private MyCustomRabbitMQConsumer rabbitConsumer;
    private String queueName;

    public ChildActor(String queueName) {
        this.queueName = queueName;
    }

    @Override
    public void preStart() {
        Connection connection = RabbitMQConnection.getConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        String main_queue_name = ConfigFactory.load().getString("rabbitmq.default_queue");
        channel.queueDeclare(queueName, false, false, false, null);

        rabbitConsumer = new MyCustomRabbitMQConsumer(getSelf());
        channel.basicConsume(queueName, true, rabbitConsumer);
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {

        if(msg instanceOf String) {
            String strMsg = (String) msg;
            JsonNode jsonMsg = Json.parse(message);

            // Call some function to process the message
        }
    }
}
```

This should work for n number of actors.